# JPlayer + MVC3 + IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, mediaelement.js, jplayer

I cant get the JPlayer to work in IE9. The examples work in it (IE9 asks to allow activation of active x controls first). But when I try to reproduce the examples in an MVC3 app, it doesnt play the video. I know this is a question that has been asked many times but I cant seem to solve the problem (in the context of an mvc3 app) even with the "solution" attribute for the JPlayer. I think im missing something but I dont know what it is. I also get the same result from mediaelement.js.

Anybody knows about this issue?

Comment: jPlayer is simply html5 based plugin who use Flash as fallback (in the case of feature missing in browser). read http://jplayer.org/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work only in the published version by configuring the mime types in the IIS. I added the mime types for mp4 format.